# Is it possible to give others access to Google Contacts without Google Apps?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

Is it possible for me to allow other Google users to view my contacts in Google Contacts, or perhaps only certain groups of contacts? Or is this a feature I'd need Google Apps for?

Answer (score 4):

With the *delegate option* that's possible:
[image]

> To delegate your contacts:
>
> 1. Go to [Google Contacts](http://www.google.com/contacts).
> 2. Click the **More** pulldown menu immediately above your contacts list and select *Manage Delegation Settings*.
> 3. In the **Add people** text box, enter the email addresses of the users you wish to share your contacts.
> 4. Click **Share & save** to finish granting the specified users access to your contacts.

[Reference](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2590392).

Comment: There's no such option in Google Contacts for me, and the link you reference is to the Google Apps version of Contacts. Is there any way to do this with the free, public version of Google Contacts?

Comment: You are correct. Then the answer to your question is: **No** and **Yes**

Answer (score 2):

As Jacob mentioned, to my knowledge, the only way to currently do this is via Google Apps accounts & Delegation. I don't think a way exists to do it with a standard account.

Your best bet might be to look for a CRM that syncs with Google Contacts - it might be a little overkill for your needs (depending on the context), but it might work. However, in my research it seems like a good number of the CRMs are based on Google Apps accounts only, so that could be a roadblock. But worth looking into further.

We're currently trying to solve this problem at [FullContact](http://www.fullcontact.com/) (yes, I work for them, so take my recommendation with a grain of salt - I'm biased). Our cloud address book pulls in Google Contacts and lets you organize and create shared lists of contacts, then syncs directly back to Google Contacts. We'll begin releasing beta invites in the near future - but unfortunately, it doesn't solve your problem now.

At the moment, since I'm not aware of any add-on app that offers this functionality, the easiest path to your result would probably be to just upgrade to a Google Apps account and call it good.

Comment: The website you provided isn't working :(

Comment: Uh-oh - thanks! I'll update link.

Answer (score 0):

I build [Shared Contacts Manager](http://sharedcontactsmanager.com/) exactly for this purpose. Please have a look. You can easily [share Google contacts](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/share_google_contacts_with_shared_contac/452164027617) with your team with one click.